# Jquery get div's current label and populate

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have multiple divs and each div has a textbox and a label. and I need to populate some text in a label when textbox is on .focus

script so far:

```
 $(function () {
   $('input:text').focus(function () {
     //how do I get the current label and populate with some text? and when clicking on a 
    //different textbox, I want to clear the previous label and just show the current
    //div's label with some data
 });
});
```

e.g.

```
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title)
    <label>
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
    <label>
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address)
    <label>
    </label>
</div>
```

thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example made for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/KhQtx/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" title="Tittle" value=""/>
    <label>
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" title="Name" value=""/>
    <label>
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" title="Address" value=""/>
    <label>
    </label>
</div>​
```

JS:

```
$('input:text').focus(function () {
   // clean label
   $('input:text').next('label').html("");

   // get input title
   var title = $(this).attr('title');            

   // add html to label from input title
   $(this).next('label').html(title);
});​
```

Comment: You really, really don't need to post the screenshot. Our browsers render the page just fine.

Comment: Believe me it really, really fails sometimes. I answered previous questions with lot of code and I waste time formatting all code.

Comment: The point of putting the actual code is so people can copy and paste it easily. There's also no guarantee that your image hosting service will be there tomorrow. What you need to do is learn to use the code-formatting tools that SO has built-in.

Comment: It seems that you don't know how to use this site. It uploads every image to it's server and I am not a software fanatic, sometimes I paste code snippets from IDE and I waste time formatting all code.

Comment: You know what? Never mind. I'll do it for you. Took all of twelve seconds.

Comment: Next time I will call you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('input:text').focus(function () {
        $(this).siblings('label').empty().html('what you want..');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
var label = $(this).parent().find('label')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('input:text').focus( function(){
    $(this).next().text('text here');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:text').focus(function () {
   $('input:text').next('label').html(""); // reset all first
   $(this).next('label').html("Your text here");
});
```

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/VxP57/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
   $('input:text').focus(function () {
     // To put textboxvalue in label
     $($(this).parent().find('label')).val($(this).val());
     // To put customvalue in label
     $($(this).parent().find('label')).val("Hi i am a label");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
   $('input:text').focus(function(e){
       $('div label').text("");
       $(this).next('label').text('SomeText');
    });
});​
```

[**Example**.](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/CpaF5/)

Note: It would be better you assign a class name to your divs as follows

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    <input type="text" id="Title" />
    <label></label>
</div>
```

So you can narrow your selection like

```
       $('div.parentDiv label').text(""); 
       $(this).next('label').text('SomeText');
```

That will avoid other div's labels to being from empty.

Comment: No required to give div's id. Using "this" , you will get currently focus textbox. Using parent selector you will get the currently focus textbox div and then using find we will get label. So it will not reflect in all other labels.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the actual question and didn't see my example too. How do you clear other labels in your answer. See my example and try to understand what I said.

Comment: Yeah that was my mistak. But still it's was not required to give id to each div. We can easily achieve it by giving class name to each label and before assigning a value to label we will clear all the labels. For example  <label class="Clear"></label><br/> <label class="Clear"></label><br/> <label class="Clear"></label> and on focus function we first line will be $("label.Clear").val("")

Comment: Same approach, I just said to assign class name (not id) to divs and you are thinking of class name for labels.